# How much data can ViewBag, ViewData, Tempdata hold

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag, viewdata

What is the maximum size that ViewBag, ViewData, Tempdata can hold?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Viewbag is dynamic, ViewData is a dictionary. So, the limit is untill run out of memory but the thought to dump huge data through viewbag is a bad idea. Instead use View Model.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post that describes best practices when using TempData:

[When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications)

This one goes even further:

[When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData is ?](http://www.gregshackles.com/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/)

Bottom is: By default, TempData is stored in the Session object. 
So the limit is the limit of your Session object. 
See this post for some insight.

Things to consider:

Generally, Session is stored in workerprocess memory eg.: in RAM....
To increase the amount of available memory, check the memory limit of your Application Pool in IIS.
For a more in-depth view of the Session object, check this doc at MSDN:

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)